# Continue loop after exception is excepted

Tags: python, sql, loops, exception

I have a loop with a `try...except`:

```
try:
    for sqlcommand in sqlcommands:
        cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as err:
    print "Programming error spotted. Message -->"
    print err
```

This loop creates tables in SQL. But I want here is if there is already table(Programming exception is generated), print the message under exception but continue loop, not stop it. Can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to change the order of `try` statement:

```
for sqlcommand in sqlcommands:
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as err:
        print "Programming error spotted. Message -->"
        print err
```

In this case while iterating the loop, for each query the `try except` block will run and if error is found the main `for` loop iteration would still be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
for sqlcommand in sqlcommands:
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as err:
        print "Programming error spotted. Message -->"
        print err
```